# Identify cause of graphic errors

Tags: macos, imac, ssd, memory, gpu

I have a late 2006 iMac with Intel Core2Duo, 64-bit (32 bit EFI) with some upgraded parts:

- 2*2GB RAM (only 3 GB can be used)
- 100GB SSD which has been running for 3 years now with trim-enabler

In the SnowLopard-Server instance which I had previously installed on it, I started to get visual errors, which got more and more over time. For example windows were blank, but the elements inside were still functional.

It seemed like a problem with the GPU to me, but I wanted to make sure and installed a MacOS Lion on it. During installation process, when loaded from the USB, there were no errors at all. But after installation and booting from the hard-drive, I got the errors again. I also tried to start a linux from a cd on that mac and there were no errors either.

This sounds like a problem with the SSD, doesn't it? Can I test this somehow before I buy a new SSD?

Comment: If you suspect a failure with the drive, get some drive diagnostics and test out.  I like [Disk Drill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/).  The diags are free.

Comment: @Allan can I install it on a USB and run it from the boot-menu? or do I need to run a recovery OS from a flash-drive?

Comment: Since you already installed the OS on a USB, just run it from there.